conversion of all values to zero during the matrix multiplication with a scalar in the implementation of a neural network in C
I am implementing a neural network in C programming in C. I have faced a problem in the backpropagation part. IN this part where in theory of formulas where we divide the values by X. I am getting all the values to zero. When this happens, the weights are not updated. I am new to this programming language just coupe of months of reading this language. I want to understand why I am getting this error. You can look at code line no 369 and 372.
I was expecting the values to change in every time in each iteration such at certain time I would get the best possible result.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define X 59999
#define Pi 785
#define IN 784
#define MAX_ROWS 60000
#define MAX_COLS 785
#define MAXCHAR 60000
#define lr 0.1

//Define the structure of the code
typedef struct {
    double **entries;
    int rows;
    int columns;
} Array;
// Create a function that returns a pointer to the structure
Array *matrixformation(int r, int c) {
    Array *matrix = malloc(sizeof(Array));
    (*matrix).rows = r;
    (*matrix).columns = c;
    (*matrix).entries = malloc(r * sizeof(double *));
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
        (*matrix).entries[i] = malloc(c * sizeof(double));
    }
    return matrix;
}

// Free the Array
void freematrix(Array *m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m).rows; i++) {
        free((*m).entries[i]);
    }
    free((*m).entries);
    free(m);
}

// Print the given Array
void print(Array *m) {
    printf("%d\t%d\n", (*m).rows, (*m).columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m).rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*m).columns; j++) {
            printf("%lf", (*m).entries[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

// Create a random array generator
void randomize(Array *m, int rows, int columns) {
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            (*m).entries[i][j] = (((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)-0.5)*0.1;
        }
    }
}
Array *multiply(Array *m1, Array *m2) {
    if ((*m1).rows != (*m2).rows || (*m1).columns != (*m2).columns) {
        printf("Dimension kMismatch");
        return NULL; // Return NULL if dimensions don't match
    } else {
        Array *m = matrixformation((*m1).rows, (*m1).columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < (*m1).rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (*m1).columns; j++) {
                (*m).entries[i][j] = (*m1).entries[i][j] * (*m2).entries[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}


Array *add(Array *a1, Array *a2) {
    if ((*a1).rows != (*a2).rows || (*a1).columns != (*a2).columns) {
        printf("Dimension Mismatch");
    } else {
        Array *m = matrixformation((*a1).rows, (*a2).columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < (*a1).rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (*a2).columns; j++) {
                (*m).entries[i][j] = (*a1).entries[i][j] + (*a2).entries[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
//Subtracts two arrays in the function.
Array *subtract(Array *a1, Array *a2) {
    if ((*a1).rows != (*a2).rows || (*a1).columns != (*a2).columns) {
        printf("Dimension Mismatch");
    } else {
        Array *m = matrixformation((*a1).rows, (*a2).columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < (*a1).rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (*a1).columns; j++) {
                (*m).entries[i][j] = (*a1).entries[i][j] - (*a2).entries[i][j];
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
//Function for the dot product of the matrix.
Array *dot(Array *m1, Array *m2) {
    if ((*m1).columns != (*m2).rows) {
        printf("Wrong dimension");
    } else {
        Array *m = matrixformation((*m1).rows, (*m2).columns);
        for (int i = 0; i < (*m1).rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < (*m2).columns; j++) {
                double res = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < (*m2).rows; k++) {
                    res += (*m1).entries[i][k] * (*m2).entries[k][j];
                }
                (*m).entries[i][j] = res;
            }
        }
        return m;
    }
}
//Function for the multiplication of the matrix by a scalar
Array *scalarm(Array *m1, double n) {
    Array *m = matrixformation(m1->rows, m1->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m1->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m1->columns; j++) {
            m->entries[i][j] = n * m1->entries[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
//Addition of the scalar to the Matrix
Array *scalarad(Array *m1, double n) {
    Array *m = matrixformation((*m1).rows, (*m1).columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m1).rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*m1).columns; j++) {
            (*m).entries[i][j] = n + (*m1).entries[i][j];
        }
    }
    return m;
}
//The transpose of the matrix can be calculated as.
Array *trans(Array *m) {
    Array *mat = matrixformation((*m).columns, (*m).rows);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m).rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*m).columns; j++) {
            (*mat).entries[j][i] = (*m).entries[i][j];
        }
    }
    return mat;
}
//Relu Activation Functiondouble relu(double lo1[X][10]) {
Array *relu(Array *m) {
    // Create a new matrix to store the result
    Array *result = matrixformation((*m).rows, (*m).columns);

    for (int i = 0; i < (*m).rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*m).columns; j++) {
            // Apply ReLU activation function
            if ((*m).entries[i][j] < 0) {
                (*result).entries[i][j] = 0; // Store modified value in the result matrix
            } else {
                (*result).entries[i][j] = (*m).entries[i][j]; // Keep non-negative values unchanged
            }
        }
    }

    return result; // Return the modified matrix
}
//Softmax Activation Function
Array *softmax(Array *m) {
    if (m == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid input matrix");
        return NULL;
    }

    Array *result = matrixformation(m->rows, m->columns);
    if (result == NULL) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed");
        return NULL;
    }

    double sum_exp = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            sum_exp += exp(m->entries[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < m->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m->columns; j++) {
            result->entries[i][j] = exp(m->entries[i][j]) / sum_exp;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

Array *deriv_relu(Array *m) {
    Array *result = matrixformation((*m).rows, (*m).columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*m).rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (*m).columns; j++) {
            if ((*m).entries[i][j] < 0) {
                (*result).entries[i][j] = 0;
            } else {
                (*result).entries[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
Array *read_csv(char *filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Error opening file %s.\n", filename);
        return NULL;
    }

    char line[MAXCHAR];
    Array *arr = matrixformation(MAX_ROWS, MAX_COLS);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ROWS; i++) {
        if (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file) == NULL) {
            printf("Error reading data from file.\n");
            fclose(file);
            return NULL;
        }
        char *token = strtok(line, ",");
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS && token != NULL; j++) {
            arr->entries[i][j] = atof(token); // Convert string to double
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }

    fclose(file);
    return arr;
}
double accuracy(Array *softmaxapplied, Array *arr2)
    {
        double sum=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        int label = (int)(*arr2).entries[i][0]; // Extract label from arr2
        sum+=(*softmaxapplied).entries[label][i];
     }
    sum=sum/X;
    return sum;
    }
void splitArray(Array *arr, Array **arr1, Array **arr2) {
    // Create arr1 starting from second row and second column
    *arr1 = matrixformation(arr->rows - 1, arr->columns - 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < arr->rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < arr->columns; j++) {
            (*arr1)->entries[i - 1][j - 1] = arr->entries[i][j];
        }
    }

    //arr2 which is the first column starting from the second row
    *arr2 = matrixformation(arr->rows - 1, 1);
    for (int i = 1; i < arr->rows; i++) {
        (*arr2)->entries[i - 1][0] = arr->entries[i][0];
    }
}
Array *onehot(Array *arr2) {
    Array *ideal = matrixformation(10, X);
    for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
        int label = (int)(*arr2).entries[i][0]; // Extract label from arr2
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if (j == label) {
                (*ideal).entries[j][i] = 1; // Set 1 for the correct class
            } else {
                (*ideal).entries[j][i] = 0; // Set 0 for other classes
            }
        }
    }
    return ideal;
}

Array* sumcol(Array* dz1) {
    double sum;
    Array* result = matrixformation(10, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < dz1->rows; i++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < dz1->columns; j++) {
            sum += dz1->entries[i][j];
        }
        result->entries[i][0] = sum;
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    double inter1;
    double inter2;
    double acc;
    double val=0;
    Array*db1=matrixformation(10,1);
    Array*db2=matrixformation(10,1);
    Array *arr = read_csv("mnist_train.csv");
    if (arr == NULL) {
        printf("Failed reading the contents of the file");
    }
    Array *arr1, *arr2;
    splitArray(arr, &arr1, &arr2);
    Array *transposedinput = trans(arr1);

    //Upto this point we have arr1 that represents the input that we need to supply
    //Arr 2 is the labels that we need to supply
    //Transpose arr1
    ///////////////////
    /////////////////
    //Initializing the random value of weights
    int wrows1 = 10;
    int wcolumns1 = 784;
    int wrows2 = 10;
    int wcolumns2 = 10;
    Array *weights1 = matrixformation(wrows1, wcolumns1);
    randomize(weights1, wrows1, wcolumns1);
    Array *bias1=matrixformation(10,1);
    randomize(bias1,10,1);
    Array *bias2=matrixformation(10,1);
    randomize(bias2,10,1);
    //Randomize Weights for the second time
    Array *weights2 = matrixformation(wrows2, wcolumns2);
    randomize(weights2, wrows2, wcolumns2);
    //Loop starts from here
    double iter=0;
    for (int loop=0; loop<X; loop++)
    {
    double weightsum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<(*weights1).rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<(*weights1).columns; j++){
            weightsum+=(*weights1).entries[i][j];
        }
    }
    printf("The weight sum is %lf",weightsum);
    Array *dotproduct1 = dot(weights1, transposedinput);
    printf("Weights 1 columns is %d", weights1->columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*dotproduct1).rows; i++) {
            inter1=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < (*dotproduct1).columns; j++) {
        // Update the value of (*dotproduct1).entries[i][j] by adding inter1 to its initial value
        (*dotproduct1).entries[i][j] += inter1;
    }
    // Increment inter1 by the corresponding bias value for the next row
    inter1 += (*bias1).entries[i][0];
    }
    Array *reluapplied = relu(dotproduct1);
    Array *dotproduct2 = dot(weights2, reluapplied);
    for (int i = 0; i < (*dotproduct2).rows; i++) {
        inter1=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < (*dotproduct2).columns; j++) {
        // Update the value of (*dotproduct1).entries[i][j] by adding inter1 to its initial value
        (*dotproduct2).entries[i][j] += inter1;
    }
    // Increment inter1 by the corresponding bias value for the next row
    inter1 += (*bias2).entries[i][0];
    }
    //Applying the softmax activation function in this code we get
    Array *softmaxapplied = softmax(dotproduct2);
    //Backward Propagation Begins.
    Array *ideal=onehot(arr2);
    printf("Error hERE");
    Array *error=subtract( softmaxapplied, ideal);

    //Calculation of derivative of the second layer we get as
    Array* treluapplied=trans(reluapplied);
    Array*dw2=dot(error,treluapplied);
     double dic=0.1;
    Array*ddw2=scalarm(dw2,dic);
    db2=sumcol(error);
    Array*ddb2=scalarm(db2,dic);
    //Calculation of derivative of the first layer we get as
    Array*tweights2=trans(weights2);
    Array*derirelu=deriv_relu(dotproduct1);
    Array*dz1=dot(tweights2,error);
    Array*ddz1=multiply(dz1,derirelu);
    Array*tone_column_input=trans(transposedinput);
    Array*dw1=dot(ddz1,tone_column_input);//intial input that we transposed later.
    printf("..........................................................................");
    printf("..........................................................................");
    Array*ddw1=scalarm(dw1,dic);
    print(ddw1);
    db1=sumcol(ddz1);
    Array*ddb1=scalarm(db1,dic);
    //Updating Part
    Array*scaled_dw1=scalarm(ddw1,lr);
    Array*scaled_dw2=scalarm(ddw2,lr);
    Array*scaled_db1=scalarm(ddb1,lr);
    Array*scaled_db2=scalarm(ddb2,lr);
    // Update Weights 1
    for (int i = 0; i < weights1->rows; i++) {
        val=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < weights1->columns; j++) {
         val=weights1->entries[i][j]-scaled_dw1->entries[i][j];
        weights1->entries[i][j]=val;
        }
    }
    // Update Weights 2
    for (int i = 0; i < weights2->rows; i++) {
    val=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < weights2->columns; j++) {
        val=weights2->entries[i][j] - scaled_dw2->entries[i][j];
        weights2->entries[i][j]=val;
        }
    }
    weightsum=0;
    for (int i=0; i<(*weights1).rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<(*weights1).columns; j++){
            weightsum+=(*weights1).entries[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bias1->rows; i++) {
            val=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < bias1->columns; j++) {
       val= bias1->entries[i][j]+scaled_db1->entries[i][j];
        bias1->entries[i][j]=val;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < bias2->rows; i++) {
            val=0;
    for (int j = 0; j < bias2->columns; j++) {
        val= bias2->entries[i][j]+scaled_db2->entries[i][j];
        bias2->entries[i][j]=val;
        }
    }
    printf("The weight sum is %lf\n",weightsum);
    acc=accuracy(softmaxapplied,arr2);
    printf("Accuracy: %lf",acc);
    iter++;
    int label = (int)(*arr).entries[loop+1][0];
    printf("The correct answer is: %d", label);
    printf("The iteration %lf\n", iter);
}

    return 0;
}



Side note: Things like (*matrix).rows are commonly written in the equivalent form: matrix->rows

Note that in matrixformation you probably want to verify that malloc succeeded. In the loop, if malloc fails, you'll want to free previously allocated rows to avoid a memory leak.

Note that for functions add() and subtract(), compiler reports "warning: control reaches end of non-void function" for the partial handling of the failure cases.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. Then come back and [edit] your question to reduce your source code to a [mre], please, currently it is far too big. Please make sure it builds without errors and warnings with the maximum warning level.

@SupportUkraine this is because i iterated through the loop, and if in the process of iteration the value of j matches the correct label than it would go that spot in the column and make the value 1 else 0, the outer loop is for iterating through each training examples or columns.

@Chris does not freeing the memory leads to such cases?, like everything is fine, I checked through each matrix, calculated their sum and verified it. When the code reaches to a step scalarm(dw1,dic) it justs converts everything zero.

@Avi berger thanks for the comment, but i dont undestand it clearly, everything in the code seems fine, I checked through each matrix, calculated their sum and verified it. When the code reaches to a step scalarm(dw1,dic) it justs converts everything zero. it just turns zero and after that weights are not updated. it remains as it is. And the accuracy is just the same.

@mechengics Why does randomize(Array *m, int rows, int columns)  use parameters rows, columns instead of m->rows, m->columns?

@mechengics, Note that multiply() is not performing standard matric multiplication.

@mechengics return NULL; // Return NULL if dimensions don't match is in multiply() but missing in many others.

@mechengics for (int j = 0; j < MAX_COLS && token != NULL; j++) { deserve a check after the loop to know enough tokens were parsed.

@mechengics Consider replacing all error message to output on stderr rather than stdout.  Stuff like printf("Invalid input matrix");, without a flush may be stuck in the buffered stdout and never seen before an abnormal exit.

@chux-ReinstateMonica oh thanks for reading the code and the help and regarding the matrix multiplication i want to do element wise multiplication. I will try your suggestions.

My comments where more general, not focused directly on your issue. The first was a style issue that affects readers, but has no impact on operation of the code. The second was about 2 errors in the code that the compiler detects & warns about. These need to be fixed, but are not necessarily related to the problem you are experiencing. They do highlight that your error handling has holes.

I looked at your scalarm() and the only issues I found were that it does not handle potential failure of matrixformation() and that matrixformation() does not handle potential malloc() failures. Other than that, if an issue is occurring there, it could be a symptom of a problem that actually occurred earlier. Purely as a guess, I'd suspect some failure or bug related to memory handling. I'd suggest tightening up your error handling, working up a [MRE], and using a debugger.

Regarding the malloc failures, unless you plan on some sort of graceful handling (e.g. in an interpreted environment that is probably needed) just log an error and abort and let the OS take care of cleaning up the memory. Or if you want to be lazy don't even do that, let the resulting segmentation fault happen, and let the OS provide the user with a message about it crashing (though it won't necessarily convey that it was because it ran out of memory).
